# Errors when installing karma througth terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal, karma-runner

I type `npm install -g karma` and get the following result every time I try:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/Sasha/.npm/karma/0.13.10/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "karma"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Sasha/npm-debug.log
```

Please help!Cannot proceed with my tutorial book!

Answer (score 0):

It's a permissions error. Run the command as the root user (as it clearly suggests in the error):

```
sudo npm install -g karma
```